# Problems with get for mobile

Tags: php, javascript, mobile, get

```
Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. index.php:8
Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. index.php:8
Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "maximum-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. index.php:8
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jQueryJson.js:156
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js:8
Failed to load resource
```

Hello i'm having some problems with the get i have try to talk to a professor of mine but he couldn't explain me what is my error or how can i solve my probleme. This is my mobile page and i really want to put this in order if anyone could help i apriciate

Thanks in advence

Comment: It will be helpful for us to see your PHP code in addition to the errors/warnings.

Comment: Maybe you should show the javascript that is causing the error, though it seems clear that at a minimum, you need to include jQuery.

Comment: "This is my mobile page" <-- where?

Comment: If your professor has no clue, makes me wonder how he is teaching the class. lol

Comment: @epascarello if the professor is teaching some kind of computer course at all...

Answer (score 3):

Well the first error is yelling about the syntax. It says replace the semicolons with commas.

You have something like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

and it wants

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

And the next error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This is saying it did not load a file and by the looks of `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jQueryJson.js:156` it looks like you do not have the jQuery file uploaded.

Comment: ajax, ajax_framework, Default, javascript_a1cb3a5978, jqm-docs, jquery.mobile-1.0.min, jquery.mobile-1.2.0, jquery.typewatch, jquery-1.7.1.min, jquery-1.7, jQueryJason, jStorage. this are my list of javascript

Comment: What do the includes look like on the page?

Comment: looks normal but when i use google chrome console to search the elements they give me errors in getting the scripts and that might be the problem that i have when i try the login and the regist forms